# How to fillna() with mean of left- and right- column neighbor cells, row by row?

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I'd like to replace `nan`s in a dataframe with:

- If `nan` is in between two columns with values, with the mean of both columns ('prev' and 'next')
- Else, keep the same path of the series.

For instance:

```
In[1]:
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2,np.nan,np.nan], [np.nan, 4,6,8],[3,np.nan,6,np.nan]], columns=['A', 'B','C','D'])

Out[2]: 
     A    B    C    D
0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  4.0  6.0  8.0
2  3.0  NaN  6.0  NaN

Desired output:

Out[2]: 
     A    B    C   D
0  1.0  2.0  4.0  6.0
1  3.0  4.0  6.0  8.0
2  3.0  4.0  6.0  8.0
```

I have tried without much success:

```
for col in df.columns:
    for i in range(len(df.columns)-1):
        prev    = df[df.columns[i-1]]
        nextval = df[df.columns[i+1]]
        df[col] = df[col].fillna((nextval+prev)/2)
```

Comment: This is an interpolation. Use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html ; apply it row-wise. EDIT: I just noticed you're doing extrapolations too, I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do that or how legitimate such extrapolation would be, especially considering a non-linear function.

Comment: you are essentially looking for some interpolation and extrapolation methodology. I have no idea what does 'same path' mean (same slope? doesn't look like). I also have no clue why B2 is 4 not 4.5.

Comment: Your explanatio and example are unclear: look at the NaN row 0, column 'C'. Its right-hand neighbor (row 0, col 'D') is NaN. But you somehow get 4.0, which *isn't* 6.0 backfilled. So where did the 4.0 come from (was it "forward-filled" from the 4.0 in row 3 column 'B'), and what does *keep the same path of the series"* mean? I think in that case you really want to unroll the 2D array into a 1D series, and do forward-fill. Right?

Comment: ...and you don't mean the *"mean of both columns (prev and next)"*, you mean *"the mean of the left- and right-neighboring cells"*. Because the mean of the entire column 'B' is 3.0 and the mean of column 'D' is 8.0

Answer (score 2):

You could use fillna() twice: one with method "bfill", one with method "ffill" and then average them.